# Typo3 7.6 activate recursive delete?

Tags: recursion, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I would like to know how to activate recursive deletes in typo3 7.6.2. All google results where for old versions which suggested going to users and changing it there. But I looked trough all the possible tabs for an admin user under backend users and couldn't find an option to activate it. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is still there where it always was.

After login open the settings of the your logged users (don't edit the BE record within Backend users module) and there on the `Edit & Advanced functions` you'll find fields for recursive copying/deleting...

[image]

Comment: I was unable to find it because in older screenshots the tab was placed on the exact place where backend users is now. I thought this was the same thing, didn't realize they moved it to the top right thank you.

Comment: Yes, also remember that some extensions which were previously placed under the User group now also went to the top (and some of them should NOT be there) I don't remember the case now, it was asked several weeks ago on the StackOverflow

Comment: Hi, I do not see the settings of the loggin user. Might I install any extention or is there some ext missing? How can I re-envoke the user settings panel? Thanks